# Cannot read data from Firestore - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a simple Vue.js app with Firebase as a backend. When I'm trying to list render I cannot display the intended property from Firebase. I'm still a newbie in all of this and I couldn't make it work with the other posts. I think I'm reading data incorrectly from Firebase so my routing is incorrect.

This is how I structure add data to Firebase which works:
[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQDpy.png)

ChatUI.vue:

```
<div @v-for="message in messages" :key="message.message" class="incoming_msg">
              <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                  <p>{{message.message}}</p>
                  <span class="time_date">11:01 AM | June 9</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

main.js:

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    name: "ChatUI";
    return {
      message: '',
      messages: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveMessage() {
      //save to firestore
      db.collection("chat").add({
        message: this.message,
        time: new Date()
      });
      this.message = null;
    },
    fetchMessages() {
      db.collection("chat")
        .orderBy("time")
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          let allMessages = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            allMessages.push(doc.data());
          });
          this.messages = allMessages;
        });
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchMessages();
  }
};
```

Comment: Does "message" that you use as key in the v-for is a unique property in all the elements you are iterating? Plus, key should be a string without spaces.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Comment: @Raffobaffo that might be it, cause the console is saying that it cannot read property 'message' of null. However, I tried the v-for documentation but still couldn't make it work

Comment: That means that the iterated property is null (as obvious :) ). I see it can be for two reasons: that can happen before your fetchMessages has completed, or the result you get from it are not what you expect. Try to console.log this.messages when they should get populated. Here -->         .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          let allMessages = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            allMessages.push(doc.data());
          });
          this.messages = allMessages;
          console.log(this.messages)
        });

Answer (score 0):

@Mill @Raffobaffo, as you have said in comments, May be the response from firebase coming after the method completes. So try using async await functions.

and it's better to set a key something other than `message.message`

like this,

```
<div @v-for="(message,name,index) in messages" :key="index" class="incoming_msg">
```

```
 methods: {
    saveMessage : async function () {
      //save to firestore
      await db.collection("chat").add({
        message: this.message,
        time: new Date()
      });
      this.message = null;
    },
    fetchMessages : async function () {
      await db.collection("chat")
        .orderBy("time")
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          let allMessages = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            allMessages.push(doc.data());
          });
          this.messages = allMessages;
        });
    }
  },
  created : async function () {
    await this.fetchMessages();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I have eventually figured it out. It was the '@' before v-for that was causing trouble and yeah I should have definitely chosen a better name for the key